# how to access the thread running the Runnable inside a Runnable class but outside of the run method?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i want to call the Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); method in the code below to cause an interrupt and the Logcat to print out,   Log.e("", "interrupted " + e.toString()); however in order to this i need to access the thread running the runnable from inside the interruptThread() method.  It is a member class of the StopIt class.

however any code running inside the interruptThread() method is running on the main UI thread. so when i call Thread.currentThread().interrupt() it is called on the main UI thread.

how to i get access to the worker or background thread that is running the Runnable from inside the in interruptThread() method?

```
public class StopIt implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {

     try {

     Thread.sleep(10000);

     } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        // this Log message should print out if working correctly
        // when the interruptThread() method below is called on this Thread
        Log.e("", "interrupted " + e.toString());

     }

 }

 public void interruptThread() {

     // determines which thread this code is running on,
     // UI or other thread
     // returns true if the thread is the UI thread
     if(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {

     Log.e("Thread check", "MAIN UI THREAD"); // <-- RESULT OF TEST

   } else {

     Log.e("Thread check", "other thread NOT main UI thread");

   }

     // calls interrupt on the main UI thread not the Runnable
     // how to get this to interrupt the Runnable thread above?
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

 }

}
```

Comment: How do you start the `StopIt` runnable? Have you tried to just save a reference to the `Thread` object that runs it and then call `interrupt()` on that object?

Comment: i was trying out a way to do that internally, and i think i found out a few seconds ago.  by creating a Thread object  as member of the StopIt class,, Thread internalThread = null; , and inside the run method, internalThread = Thread.currentThread();  and then call internalThread.interrupt()  in the interruptThread() method.  it seems to be working but there is some delay. i am testing it now

Comment: actually that is working ok,  the delay was i accidentally running it in the debugger.  running it normally and it is vary fast. instant.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted, for other people who will get here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting Kevik's comment to an answer:

creating a Thread object as member of the StopIt class,, Thread internalThread = null; , and inside the run method, internalThread = Thread.currentThread(); and then call internalThread.interrupt() in the interruptThread() method